# S Parameters in HFSS

Tags: antenna-theory, rfi, antenna-system, microwave

I'm new to HFSS Software and I'm trying to plot Scattering parameters for a dielectric resonator excited by a probe (shown in image). I know that the top cylinder has a higher dielectric than the bottom cylinder. I also know that the cavity is a metal. The structure is from chapter 11 of "Microwave Filters for Communication Systems: Fundamentals, Design, and Applications" book (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/book/8341843). Now my questions are:

- Do I provide waveport excitation to outer part of the probe?
- Since the cavity is a metal is that my ground or do I need to have a ground beneath the substrate?
- I know that inside the cavity should be air. How do I make that happen in HFSS?
- I need to basically cut a hole in the cavity structure to place the probe in right?
- What is the difference between waveport and lumped port excitation?
- What is the difference between modal and terminal solution types?

Help in any of the questions will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi John, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between waveport and lumped port excitation?

**A lumped excitation** is applied at a single mathematical point, it can be voltage or current

**A waveport** is applied over a cross-sectional area. Such as the end/beginning of a transmission line on a PCB. You apply it like you would "see" the electrical field between line and GND plane.